# Is there a way to hash a turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, discrete-mathematics, hash-tables, hashing

If we have a Turing machine with various $\delta(q_i, a_i) = (q_j, a_j, Direction)$ where Direction can be L or R(denoting the movement of head), can we encode it uniquely to some natural number(which can later be decoded to give us back the deltas) ? It doesn't matter if all the natural numbers map one-to-one to all the Turing machines.

Comment: The basic primitive that I like to use here is called a pairing function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Any Turing machine can be represented as a bit string (print out the description of the Turing machine).  Any bit string can be encoded as a natural number (prepend a 1 bit, and view it as a binary representation of a number).

Comment: I read the description number of Turing machine, it answered my query. Thank you!